# Expiring content creates 404s with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a virtual host that includes the following `location` block:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name ~^(?<username>[^.]+)\.project*/\.client\.com$; 
  root        /home/$username/project/app/webroot;
  index       index.php; 

  access_log /var/log/nginx/project.sandbox.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/project.sandbox.error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;
  } 

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/includes/php;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
  include /etc/nginx/includes/ignore;
}
```

I've never had problems before, but I just added a feature that allows users to upload & store files. If the user uploads pdfs, txt files, etc. all is well and I can load the upload just fine via its URL. Images, on the other hand, not so much. 404s everywhere.

I've narrowed it down to this block, but I don't understand it. Other image assets load fine. The only difference, which may make all the difference, is that uploaded assets aren't loaded into the webroot as defined by the `server` block's `root` directive. Uploads are stored in `/opt/www/app/plugins/...`. Is there any reason that should matter? My front controller handles the routing for uploaded assets.

I'd like to cache/expire content, but I need to fix the 404s first.

Comment: Please include the rest of the relevant `server` block.

Comment: That can't possibly be the entire `server` block.

Comment: It wasn't. Now it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)` location block catches requests for uploaded assets ending with those file extensions. Since nginx only executes a single location block at each level, your PHP script is not executed for these requests. nginx tries to serve the file directly from disk, but it can't find the uploaded asset.

You need to make this location block match stricter so that it does not match uploaded assets. For example:

```
location ~* ^/static/.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$
```

**Edit**: When I say "level" I mean nesting level. For example:

```
location / {
    location /foo {}
}

location /bar {}

location /baz {
    location /baz/quaz {}
    location ~ \.php$ {}
}
```

The `/`, `/bar` and `/baz` location blocks are at level 1. The `/foo`, `/baz/quaz` and `\.php$` location blocks are at level 2, because they're nested within a level 1 location block. Let's say that the request is for `/baz/quaz/index.php`. nginx will select the most specific level 1 location block, in this case `/baz`. No other level 1 location blocks will be processed, so the `/` block will have no effect for this request. If there are level 2 location blocks it will do the same, in this case choosing `\.php$` and ignoring `/baz/quaz`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some detail (or point me to a URL) about "nginx only executes a single location block at each level"? I'm not I understand that. What is a "level" in this context?

Comment: Since I understand better through examples, maybe the better quetion is...how would my config need to change if I want to cache both the runtime assets located somewhere in the webroot _and_ the uploaded assets in my plugin directory (`/polyclip/assets/`)?

Comment: @RobWilkerson See my edit.

Comment: Final question: When processing the level 2 block for `/baz/quaz/index.php` what makes \.php$ get executed? Would `/baz/quaz` get "expanded" to `/baz/baz/quaz` (and hence not match) or is there a specificity rule in play that the "~" triggers? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @RobWilkerson Yup, `~` blocks have a higher priority than plain paths. The documentation explains [how location blocks are chosen](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).